# C++ conditional compilation with large numbers of code files

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

I wanna compile and run one copy of C++ codes on Windows and Linux. so I need to use conditional compilation(CC). However, it comes across the problem that **how to use CC in large numbers of code files**.

Such as, I have:

```
//A.cpp
#define _WINDOWS_
#ifdef _WINDOWS_
#include <windows.h>
//some code for windows
#else
#include <pthread.h>
//some code for linux
#endif
```

and I also have B.cpp, C.cpp...

**Should I write "#define _WINDOWS_" in every single file, or is there a better way?**

And I have tried to do like this:

1. create a head file Platform.h

   ```
    #ifndef _PLAT_
    #define _PLAT_
    #define _WINDOWS_
    #endif
   ```
2. include the file Platform.h, like:

   ```
    //A.cpp
    #include "Platform.h"
    #ifdef _WINDOWS_
    #include <windows.h>
    //some code for windows
    #else
    #include <pthread.h>
    //some code for linux
    #endif
   ```
3. it compiles with errors! Maybe including `"Platform.h"` before including `<windows.h>` causes the errors.

Comment: You're better off using `_WIN32` than rolling your own.

Comment: I am feeling you need abstract factory to seperate your code into different platforms? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: what is the compile error? looks like it should work at least

Comment: when i changes "_WINDOWS_" into "_WIN_", it compiles successfully. And using _WIN32 works for me. thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some predefined macro from your compiler.

http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

```
#ifdef _WIN32
// Code specific to Windows.
#elif defined __linux__ // Many variants; check the link above.
// Code specific to Linux.
#else
// Portable code.
#endif
```

This will work in the majority of the cases.

Note that most of these macros are used to detect the *host* operating system (that is, the system in which you're building the program), not the *target* operating system (the system in which the resulting program is intended to be run). However, it is usually the case that both systems coincide. Note also that whether any of these macros are actually predefined obviously depends on your particular compiler.

If all else fails (for example, target system differs from host, or your compiler is strange enough to not predefine any system-detection macros at all), simply define any of them in the compiler's command line (for example, using `-D` in POSIX-compliant C compilers) by putting it into your build script or makefile. Don't write such `#define`s in the header themselves.

Comment: +1, but usually compiling for a different platform requires a cross-compiler which will define appropriate platform flags. Trying to get code for another platform by adjusting things manually might be an impossible fight to win.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -D_WINDOWS_ during compilation. For (3) note that headers are sensitive to ordering.

Comment: -1, this is a surefire way to confuse users with a tangled build system.

Comment: Yeah it generally depends on many factors. I work in a company with an extremely huge code-base and this has been in vogue for a decade now. Again this is an engineering problem and there are multiple instances when this approach will be good. I wouldn't issue a blanket no for this approach until the entire usecase is clear.